# Grunt --force fails with node: bad option

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have a Grunt task called `eslint:jenkins` that runs eslint on the project. In the build pipeline I run it as:

```
grunt eslint:jenkins --force --verbose
```

I use --force so the grunt will not fail even if the task fails because there are some eslint issues.

When I run this locally everything is fine. When this runs on Jenkins I get the following error:

```
<path-to-installation>/Node_10/bin/node: bad option: --force
```

For both local and Jenkins environments the versions are: Node 10.0 and grunt-cli 1.3.1.

I cannot imagine any reason why in one case the `--force` flag is propagated to Node. Can anybody give me some pointers on where to look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo npm install grunt-cli -g`

Should output something like:

```
/usr/local/bin/grunt -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt
+ grunt-cli@1.3.2
updated 2 packages in 3.056s
```

Then `grunt --force` should work for you.

(Tested on macOS Mojave)

Comment: Yeah, was fixed in 1.3.2 :)

Answer (score 3):

Same issue with node 10 and a gulp task with arguments.

```
./node_modules/.bin/gulp tasks:my-task --myoption=value
[16:14:24] Node flags detected: --myoption=value
[16:14:24] Respawned to PID: 21231
```

No issue with node 8. Did not try with node 9. There must have been a breaking change somewhere, but I can find any information on this beside this question and https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1564

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
grunt tasks:my-task **-myoption**=value, it worked for me.